# Postgres WHERE clause with infinity

Tags: postgresql

I have the following WHERE clause on a table x with column 1 as integer.
The SELECT is called in a function with parameters (a integer, b integer)

Call the function:

```
SELECT * FROM function(0, 10)
```

Script in funcion:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex x WHERE x.column1 between a and b
```

Now i miss the results where column1 is null, but in this case it is important to get these. Depends who calls the function. What should be parameter "a" to also get the null values. Or is there a way to disable the where clause depending on the paramter which are coming?

Comment: Please add sample data which explains your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution for this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex x WHERE coalesce(x.column1, 0) between a and b
```

Comment: This *looks* elegant, but do check the query plan (the function might cause indexes to be unusable)

Answer (score 0):

Add logic to admit null `column1` values:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablex x
WHERE x.column1 BETWEEN a AND b OR x.column1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is not working when i call the function with a = 1 and b = 10 i dont want to get rows where x.column1 IS NULL

Comment: Can you specify in which cases you want NULL values and in which cases you don't want them ? PS: what has "infinity" to do with NULL values ?

Answer (score 0):

To make the NULLs behave as actual values, **invert the logic**.
[and add a comment to the code, because the negation might confuse future readers/maintainers]:

---

```
 SELECT * FROM tablex x WHERE NOT x.column1 < a and NOT x.column1 >= b;
```

---

Note the above assumes you want NULLs in **both** `a` and `b` to be treated as  `-inf` and `+inf` , respectively.